# Internet Explorer 9 appearance conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have been researching all over the internet about this, and unfortunately cannot find out why this is happening.  It seems to only be happening in internet explorer 9, on certain computers.

The entire page looks like a mess only in IE 9 (some computers):

[image]

The URL of the website is [Here](http://www.go-optic.com)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening in IE9?

(NOTE: Compatibility view cleans it, but then the Js/jQuery doesn't work right).

Comment: Hi Marcus, could you share the relevant part of your code (css and html structure of the buggy part)? Also, I did a quick check in the site's source code, and my html validator gives me **hundreds** of just html errors. Of which I saw one that you put an `<html>` tag inside another `<html>` tag. With all these scripting errors, it's hard to say what is at fault here.

Comment: Hello poepje, you found double html tags on the homepage?  I wasn't able to locate another `html` tag in this script.

Comment: You have [2386 HTML Validation Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.go-optic.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)!  It's no wonder you have problems with IE.

Comment: I checked again and see it now, the error is that you have code that's inside the <html> but not the <head> nor <body> tag. Also, the html validator says '<html> previously mentioned'.

Comment: As for the last one, I'd suggest to do it like this instead: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">`

Comment: Thank you for your comment poepje, but can you explain what you mean here?  Maybe in an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, IE thought that the site was in my intranet, and rendered it in Compatibility Mode (there's a setting in IE to automatically render intranet sites in CM).
When I unchecked the box to "automatically detect intranet network", the site rendered correctly.
So your real question is how does IE determine the intranet network, and how can you force your page to NOT render in Compatibility Mode... something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546775/how-to-forcefully-set-ies-compatibility-mode-off-from-the-server-side).

Comment: Scott M, are you the OP? You are answering like you are, even though the original question was from Marcus Bennett.

Comment: @CharlieKilian, clearly that's not the case.  Look at the second paragraph where he says, _"**your** real question..."_ and _"how can **you** force..."_

Comment: Thank you Scott, but over here it looks normal when it goes into compatibility mode, not when it goes out of it.

Comment: Actually, now it looks fine without compatibility, and bad with compatibility.  I think this may be the issue.

Comment: You actually have a correct answer, thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Going on a whim here, but I think it's the usage of inline-block. I don't have IE9 installed to a point where I can use it's developer console to further inspect, but IE is known to be very bad about displaying inline-block elements.

In Google Chrome's console, I am able to replicate the same appearance using `float:left` as opposed to `display:inline-block`, so that should solve that piece of the issue.

**Edit:** The only syntax issue I see with the HTML is the placement of the `</head>` tag, which is not adjacent to the `<body>` tag.

**Edit 2:** As far as the outlining issue goes, try [using this answer to another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142866/877983)

Edited yet again to fix the display of the tags.

Comment: Not all though ie9 browsers, only some.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but how about the blue borders?

Comment: I thought those where highlights from an inspection program. I'll look into potential causes.

As far as solutions to the problem, I would just use floats. Wherever you use `display:inline-block`, replace it with `float:left`.

Comment: Nicholas, I commend you for trying but until the OP fixes most of his [2300+ Validation Issues](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.go-optic.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you're simply chasing something you'll never get your arms around.

Comment: @Sparky672 Have you looked through the errors? The markup is getting dinged almost entirely for unescaped URLs, and meta attributes that won't affect the display of the page. The misplacement of the `</head>` tag is a true markup error, but browsers will still load the stylesheets and scripts anyways. His syntax, although it should be fixed, will have no affect on the page's display.

Comment: Nicholas, How could anyone here have gone through all 2386 errors to verify that none of them could cause rendering issues?  Invalid HTML is one of the leading reasons IE slips into Compatibility Mode.  My point is that you should have a solid (valid and compliant) foundation before launching into fixes and workarounds.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for your answers and comments.  It appears it was a compatibility issue with IE, which appears to be resolved. As for the validation issues, I will look into those.  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I read your comment about the misplaced `</head>` tag, can you explain why it is misplaced? Thank you.

Comment: @Marcus Bennett You have `<link>` elements sifted throughout the document, these should be all located within the `<head>`. Also, the `<script>` tags at the bottom of the document should be within the `</body>` tag. Generally, `</head>` should be adjacent to `<body>`, and `</body>` to `</html>`.

Comment: You were very helpful Nicholas, thank you for your efforts.  Unfortunately another answerer was able to provide the exact cause of the issue, which is the compatibility issue being triggered.  However, I do thank you again for all of your help and will look into resolving these other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have blank space above your `doctype`.  IE hates this.  The `doctype` needs to be the very first thing in the file.

You also have over [2300 HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.go-optic.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) that should be investigated and rectified.  Again, IE is very sensitive to invalid HTML.

Comment: Thank you Sparky, top space removed, but still the same issue. ;(

Comment: @MarcusBennett, then look at my second point.  That's horrifically invalid HTML... IE is notorious for not dealing with this as well as others.

Comment: @Bergi, what does have to do with my answer?

Comment: It was @MarcusBennett. The validator auto-detected Doctype "XHTML 1.0 Transitional", which it is not. Served as normal HTML, there should be fewer errors