# MVC Web .Net: Intercept all calls before reaching controller?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a .Net MVC web application (Not WebAPI), and I want to intercept all calls to the web app before they reach the controller, check for a value in the request headers, and do something if the value isn't present (such as presenting a 404). What's the ideal way to do this? Keep in mind this is not a Web API application, just a simple web application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 intercept all incoming requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests)

Comment: After you check the value, are you going to pass the request to the controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what specifically you want to do, you could use a default controller which all other controllers extend. That way you can override `OnActionExecuting` or `Initialize` and do your check there.

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}

public class YourController : ApplicationController
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for global action filters.

Create a class that inherits `ActionFilterAttribute`, override `OnActionExecuting()` to perform your processing, and add an instances to global filter collection in Global.asax.cs (inside `RegisterGlobalFilters()`)

Comment: Using this approach, can you specify for which routes do you want to do this?