# setup asp.net mvc route for base url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I have this route setup I can trigger any **controllerName/actionName** url because I do not need a start **url/page**.

I do not run a web api because I want to use razor for my views.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "*", action = "*", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

but when I start my project and run my site I see the base url in the browser: `http://localhost:62127/`

giving me a 404 error.

How can I configure my project to return a 403 error which is IIS typically giving me? When directory browsing is disabled?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to return a 403? Technically, a 404 is correct here.

Comment: Yes technically it would be correct. I just want to learn. :-)

Comment: One possibility is to create a controller/action that simply returns a [`HttpStatusCodeResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult.aspx). You could also [create an ActionFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests) or intercept the request in `Application_BeginRequest`.

Comment: Is there not a elegant web.config setting without touching the code?

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't know any by heart.

Comment: You can use the  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFoundPage" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors> but that wont change the status code, I guess you could have a controller action which returned a 403 status code in the response by setting Response.StatusCode = 403;