# detect mvc controller and API controller request through HttpApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to detect that incoming request is for **MVC** controller or **API** controller through **HttpApplication**?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve what you want. Assuming you´re working with ASP.NET MVC 4+ you could use:

```
Application_BeginRequest()
```

You can register this Event in your `Global.asax.cs`

For example you could access your request like so:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Perform actions on HttpContext.Current.Request
    }
```

You can find a pretty nice overview on this event [here (DotNetPerls Example)](https://www.dotnetperls.com/application-beginrequest).

Another possible solution would be a GlobalFilter. This was already answered many times and you can get further information [Here (Stack Overflow Answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726897/6641105).

It depends on your use case what version you would prefer.