# Programmatically disable IE compatibility mode for IE8/9/10/11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsf, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

I am implementing to programmatically disable IE compatibility mode for IE8/9/10/11.
I have added:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
       .setResponseHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE");
```

But is not working in IE11.

Comment: You could try adding a meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`, that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: My plan is to do in Server side...

Comment: Why 'serverside'? Isn't xhtml serverside to?

Comment: Browsers are not driven by a server. You cannot do this by any means on the server-side. You have to rely upon the client which is always exploitable - whether you do it or not, it can always be uncovered. The code snippet you provided is merely analogous to `HttpServletResponse#setHeader(String name, String value)` under the hood. *IE compatibility mode* is ever epic fail. They should not even have provided this option.

Comment: IE 11 changed the user agent string and affiliated behavior. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#uaString

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546775/how-to-forcefully-set-ies-compatibility-mode-off-from-the-server-side