# Connect via hostname or IP act different?

Tags: asp.net, iis-8.5

I have a web page on ISS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2). Project name is KTS. Server name is MANKTS and it's IP is 10.3.11.165.

On an other computer, When I connect webpage like "http ://10.3.11.165/KTS/", everything is ok. But when I connect like "http ://MANKTS/KTS/" webpage behave an old webpage (internet explorer behave like IE7).  And my webpage looking bad.

with host:
[image: Image 1]

and wtih IP:

[image: Image 2]
And the web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="Telerik.Skin" value="Windows7" />
    <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
    <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQL_ConnectionStr" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=KTS;User ID=***;Password=***" />

    <add name="SQL_ConnectionStr_Kart" connectionString="data source=***;initial catalog=***;Password=***;persist security info=True;user id=***" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
        <globalization culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
      <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens on intranet sites in IE because the **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** setting is defaulted to on.  Unfortunately all site users have to go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings and uncheck Display intranet sites in Compatibility View.

I have no idea why MS decided to make this the default setting.

Comment: Wow, that's work! Many thanks. But I have about 100 computers:) Is not there a web.config trick bypass compatiblity view?

Comment: By design you don't have much control of the user's browser settings.  What you can do is check the version of the browser in javascript and if it's IE7, show an alert that guides them on how to fix the setting.  I don't allow access to my intranet sites unless the setting is changed.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546775/how-to-forcefully-set-ies-compatibility-mode-off-from-the-server-side  and web.config addition works for me:) many thanks.